# ORA-32031: illegal reference of a query name in WITH clause

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to create CTE with Oracle 10g and unfortunately getting the below error

> ORA-32031: illegal reference of a query name in WITH clause

Is there any way to resolve or alternate solution to make it work? (Unfortunately I've to use the old version)

Struggling with the exception and after few hours of trying as well researching, it seems to be a versioning issue that means the CTE isn't supported in the version I am working with. I am not sure but when I tried the query in SQL Server 2008, it worked just fine. This is the tried query so far:

```
with Q1 as
(
    select m.id, m.value, row_number() over (partition by id order by storedate) as n
    from sample_test_2020 m
),
Q2 as
(
    select Q1.id, value as s, n as m, lpad(n, 3, '0') as p 
    from Q1
    where value <= 8 
    union all
    select Q1.id, Q1.value + s as s, Q1.n as m, Q2.p || ',' || lpad(Q1.n, 3, '0') as p
    from Q1
    inner join Q2 on Q2.id = Q1.id and Q1.n > Q2.m and Q1.value + s <= 8
),
Q3 as
(
    select id, min(p) as p
    from Q2 
    where s = 8
    group by id
)

select * from Q3;
```

**Expected output**:

```
ID   P
1122 001,004
4466 001,004
```

**Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_TEST_2020 
(
  ID VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, STOREDATE DATE 
, VALUE NUMBER 
, INFO VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
)
```

**Sample Input**:

```
ID      STOREDATE   VALUE INFO
4466    01-JAN-20   2     DONE
4466    02-JAN-20   2     DONE
4466    03-JAN-20   2     DONE
4466    04-JAN-20   6     DONE
1122    01-JAN-20   2     DONE
1122    02-JAN-20   2     DONE
1122    03-JAN-20   2     DONE
1122    04-JAN-20   6     DONE
```

For the reference that worked in SQL Server, here is the working solution - [Working Sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=491465ea49e3b22a08f2508509f8664b)

Comment: Oracle 10 simply didn't support recursive common table expressions.

Comment: The `Q2` CTE is making references to itself.  Were you intending to run a recursive CTE?

Comment: Yes @Tim Biegeleisen. It's a recursive CTE.

Comment: OK, it seems so. But any way to get it done? I am almost giving up on that version @a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: An alternative to a recursive CTE would be `connect by`

Answer (score 3):

You need a more recent version of Oracle Database!

While you're still stuck on 10g, a `connect by` along these lines should work:

```
with rws as (
  select m.id, m.value, 
         row_number() over (
           partition by id order by storedate
         ) as rn
  from sample_test_2020 m
), tree as (
  select id, lpad ( rn, 3, '0' ) rn, prior value + value v
  from   rws
  start with value <= 8
  connect by prior rn < rn
  and prior id = id
  and prior value + value <= 8
)
  select id, min ( rn ) || ',' || max ( rn ) p
  from   tree
  group  by id;

ID      P         
1122    001,004    
4466    001,004
```

Though to be honest I'm confused as to the purpose of your query. It looks like it calculates some kind of running total - it may be possible to do this using `sum ... over ( ... )`

Comment: Though I didn't clear the logic fully but you are almost there @Chris Saxon. Here is the link and the output I am expecting actually - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fb17b40b27bbd2ba4303a9685acc788b

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? The output in the link doesn't match the expected or actual output of the recursive query in your question

Comment: Could you please see this - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=460b995ca1b02795ef591ab5c9d1c021? Checking occurrence of 8 or sum of 8 once for an id. So for 1122, first four 2 returns 8 @Chris Saxon and updating those rows that matches the criteria. Basically I am checking the sum of 8 or value 8 at the first occurrence of an id and trying to convert it to `Oracle` 10g.

Comment: Hello @Chris Saxon! Did you see the link and are you aware of the purpose now?